# Google Sheets copy value to a different tab base on another value check and lookup from a list then paste at same row but different column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for the responses and apologise for the lack of details in my previous question. I am creating my small company's Quotation & Customers List in Google Sheets with some script in it. New company and still can't afford to purchase the commercial type of system. So I am struggling to get the matching `"comName"` in QUO with the `"comNameList"` in CUS then with the result I can paste the `"refNo"` in QUO value at Column + 10 same Row of `"comName"` in CUS found from the `"comNameList"` in CUS. I have tried some workarounds but cannot get it to work. The last trial is as below where 'i' logged as -1. Hoping to improve from time to time. Any kind of help is appreciated. BTW, the comName in CUS located at A2 cell the refNo from QUO should be copied to CUS K2 cell. Thank you very much.

```
    // Save Ref. no.
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var comName = sh.getSheetByName('QUO').getRange("I4").getValues();
    Logger.log(comName);
    var refNo = sh.getSheetByName('QUO').getRange("I7").getValues();
    Logger.log(refNo);
    var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('CUS');
    var comNameList = sh2.getRange("A2:A200").getValues();
    Logger.log(comNameList);
    
    var i = comNameList.indexOf(comName); 
    Logger.log(i);
    sh2.getRange(i, i + 10).setValues([[refNo]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comName` is a 2D array of objects because you are getting it using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). As `comNameList` is also a 2D array of objects, you won't find `comName` in `comNameList`, and that's why [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1`.

A few suggestions:

- If you just need the value from one cell, it might be easier to use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) instead of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). This will set `comName` to a single value, instead of a 2D array.
- To search for `comName` using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it's probably a good idea to make `comNameList` an array with just one dimension with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns an index that starts from *0*, but you need to account for the fact you get the values from the second row (`getRange("A2:A200")`).

Based on these suggestions, the code you posted can be modified to:

```
// Save Ref. no.
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var comName = sh.getSheetByName('QUO').getRange("I4").getValue();
Logger.log(comName);
var refNo = sh.getSheetByName('QUO').getRange("I7").getValue();
Logger.log(refNo);
var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('CUS');
var comNameList = sh2.getRange("A2:A200").getValues().flat();
Logger.log(comNameList);

var i = comNameList.indexOf(comName); 
Logger.log(i);
sh2.getRange(i+2, i + 10).setValues([[refNo]]);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your thorough explanation.. You are so very kind.. I gained more knowledge from that.. Your suggestion works really good.. I change the column for target to (i+2, 11) for K Column & that's it..! Have a nice day @mshcruz ..!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. In this case, please consider accepting it as the answer for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers